# SWT on button click close current shell open a new shell

Tags: java, shell, swt

I'm new to Java. I'm trying a SWT-desktop application which has login form. When OK button is clicked, after authentication, I want to open a main window after closing the login shell. Please find below the relevant code segments.

**In Login.java**

```
btnOK.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
@Override
public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
    if(LoginAuthentication.isValidLogin(txtUname.getText(), txtPwd.getText())){
    //shell.dispose();
    MainWin win = new MainWin();                            
}
```

Everything is working but the Login shell hangs in the background, which can be seen once the MainWin shell close. If I uncomment the line containing shell.dispose(); in Login.java, then the MainWin shell opens and closes momentarily.

Can anybody please help me on this issue? Your suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thanks Rudiger for your effort to solve the problem. The code that open the login shell is as below. In LoginWin.java

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
        LoginWin window = new LoginWin();
        window.open();
   }
```

Also, in LoginWIn.java I have the following:

```
public void open() {
display = Display.getDefault();
createContents();
shell.open();
shell.layout();
while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
display.sleep();
}
}
}

protected void createContents() {
shell = new Shell( SWT.CLOSE | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL);
shell.setSize(450, 300);
shell.setText("tMailer");
shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, true));

Label lblHeading = new Label(shell, SWT.SHADOW_OUT);
lblHeading.setText("Login window");
lblHeading.setLayoutData( new GridData(SWT.CENTER, GridData.FILL_VERTICAL, true, false, 2, 1));

Group loginGr = new Group(shell, SWT.NONE);
GridData gd_loginGr = new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 
1);
loginGr.setLayoutData(gd_loginGr);
loginGr.setText("Login data");
loginGr.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 2, 
1));
loginGr.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, true));
Label lblUname = new Label(loginGr, SWT.NONE);
lblUname.setText("Username");
lblUname.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.FILL, true, 
false));
Text txtUname = new Text(loginGr, SWT.FLAT);
txtUname.setText("u");
txtUname.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false, 
3,1));
Label lblPwd = new Label(loginGr, SWT.NONE);
lblPwd.setText("Password");
lblPwd.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.FILL, true, false));

Text txtPass = new Text(loginGr, SWT.PASSWORD);
txtPwd.setText("p");    
txtPwd.setEchoChar('*');

Label lblCol1 = new Label(loginGr, SWT.NONE);   // filler for balnk grid-column
lblCol1.setText("Column-1");
lblCol1.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));
lblCol1.setVisible(false);

Button btnCancel = new Button(loginGr, SWT.FLAT);
btnCancel.setText("Cancel");
btnCancel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));
btnCancel.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
@Override
public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
shell.dispose();
}
});     

Label lblCol2 = new Label(loginGr, SWT.NONE);  // filler for gridcolumn 3
lblCol2.setText("Column-3");
lblCol2.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));
lblCol2.setVisible(false);      
Button btnOK = new Button(loginGr, SWT.FLAT);
btnOK.setText("Login");
btnOK.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));
shell.setDefaultButton(btnOK);
btnOK.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
@Override
public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
if(LoginAuthentication.isValidLogin(txtUname.getText(), txtPass.getText())){
SplashWin sw = new SplashWin();     
}
});             
shell.pack();
}
```

My SplashWin.java file has the following:

```
public class SplashWin {
private final Shell splash;
private Display display;
private int counter;

public SplashWin()
{
display = Display.getDefault();
splash = new Shell(SWT.ON_TOP | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL | SWT.NONE);
final Label lbl_img = new Label(splash, SWT.NONE);
final Image img = new Image("test.png");
lbl_img.setImage(img);
splash.open();

display.asyncExec(new Runnable()
{
public void run()
{
for(counter=0; counter<5; counter++
{
try { 
Thread.sleep(40);
}
catch(InterruptedException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
splash.close();
img.dispose();
splash.dispose();
//  Create and call open() of an ApplicationWindow object
MainWin mainWin =  new MainWin();
mainWin.open();
}
});

while(counter != 5)
{
if(!display.readAndDispatch())
{
display.sleep();
}
}

public static void main(String[] args){
new SplashWin();
} 
}
```

Hope this will equip you better to help me on the issue. Thanks again.

Comment: Please show us the code that opens the login shell

Comment: That loop calling `Thread.sleep` is blocking the UI thread for the duration of the loop (wrapping it in `asyncExec` doesn't make any difference). If you want to run code after a delay used `Display.timerExec`.